# Pine Script issue with global variable and if condition

Tags: if-statement, global-variables, return-value, pine-script

When I run this code I get consecutive times the function `strategy.close(qty_percent=50, comment="TP-Pertial)` though the `i` is 1 and not 0.

Infact, when I plot `i` I get 1 as you can see from the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6bcd.png), it is the white value.

I miss something but I don't know what.

Anyone can help me?

```
//@version=4
strategy("backtesting", initial_capital=20000, overlay = true)

//set your strategy
ema20 = ema(close, 20)
ema50 = ema(close, 50)

long = ema20 > ema50
short = ema20 < ema50

longCondition = long and long[2] and not long[3]
shortCondition = short and short[10] and not short[11] 

closeLong = ema20 < ema50 and not long[3]
closeShort = ema20 > ema50 and not short[11]

//budget is the money that you want allocate to open a position
//desiredTakeProfitPercentage is the percentage of price change you want to close your position
//tp_Value and sl_Value are the money that you want to earn from a position and max money you want to lose respectively
int budget = 10000
float desiredTakeProfitPercentage = 0.05
float desiredStopLossPercentage = 0.03
float tp_Value = 500
float sl_Value = 250
float qty_close_percentage = 0.5

bought = longCondition
entry_price = valuewhen(bought, open, 0)

float numberStocks = (budget/entry_price)
int intNumberStocks = ceil(numberStocks)
float positionValue2 = ((open - entry_price)*numberStocks) + entry_price
float changeValue = (open - entry_price) * numberStocks
float price_TPPercentage = changeValue/budget
float price_SLPercentage = changeValue/budget
float positionValue = (changeValue + (entry_price * numberStocks))
int TP_qty_close_percentage = round(qty_close_percentage + intNumberStocks)



//condition to open and close position
takeProfitValue = changeValue > tp_Value
stopLossValue = changeValue < - sl_Value
takeProfitPercentage = price_TPPercentage > desiredTakeProfitPercentage
stopLossPercentage = price_SLPercentage > price_SLPercentage

longExitPrice = (entry_price * (1 + 0.1))
longStopLossPrice = (entry_price * (1 - 0.3))

//new variables and condition after partial exit
exit_price = valuewhen(takeProfitPercentage, open, 0)
exit_tp_change = valuewhen(takeProfitPercentage, price_TPPercentage, 0)

float exit_value_position = (exit_tp_change/numberStocks)*(numberStocks*0.5)

second_takeProfitPercentage = exit_value_position > desiredTakeProfitPercentage

i=0

//plot the value on chart 
plot(entry_price, color=#aaa00b, linewidth=2)
//plot(positionValue, color=#ffffff, linewidth=1)
plot(ema20, title="20", color=#aaaa00, linewidth=1)
plot(ema50, title="50", color=#550055, linewidth=1)

//period of time you want to test
start = timestamp(2000,6,1,0,0)
end = timestamp(2020,2,1,0,0)

//when enter
if (time >=start and time <= end and strategy.position_size < 1)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=intNumberStocks, when=longCondition)

//when close
strategy.close("Long", when = closeLong, comment="closeLong")
if(i==0 and takeProfitPercentage)
    i:=1
    strategy.close("Long", qty_percent=50, comment="TP-Partial")

if(stopLossValue or stopLossPercentage)
    strategy.close("Long", comment="SL")
    i:=0
if(second_takeProfitPercentage and i==1)
    strategy.close("Long", comment= "TP-close")
    i:=0

plot(i, color=#ffffff, linewidth=4)
```

Comment: This script cannot be added to the chart. It throws an `internal server study error`. Please provide a script that works.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I uploaded an old version script. I uploaded the new version. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for uploading the correct script.
The problem is that the `i` value is not `1` like you stated in your question, but it's `0` on `25 May 01`.

[image: Screenshot i=0]

Also, instead of using `plot()` for debugging

```
plot(i, color=#ffffff, linewidth=4)
```

You should use `plotchar()` like this

```
plotchar(i, "i", "")
```

because that doesn't distort your chart.
The variable is then visible in the Data Window.

Edit: The `i` value is zero because it gets re-initialized to `0` at every bar.
Instead of using

```
i=0
```

Try using

```
var int i = 0
```

When using the `var` keyword, the variable is initialized only once, at the first bar, and it keeps it's value throught al subsequent bars (unless you assign another value to it of course).

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain the `i=0` problem.